# WebChat how to set css color for sender/receiver

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, signalr

I am working on implementing a web chat and have come up with an issue that I hope is easily solvable.

How do I change the color for the sender/receiver to differenciate them? 
I have tried to saving the colors into my db but the issue is how I can identify that I am the sender and the receivers color needs to be different.

This is how I have implemented my chat:

Chat.js

```
connection.on("SessionNotification", function (user, message) {
    var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    var p = document.createElement("span");
    var q = document.createElement("li");
    p.setAttribute("class", "Sender");
    q.setAttribute("class", "Message");
    p.textContent = user + " - " + moment(datetime).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
    q.textContent = msg;
    document.getElementById("MessageList").appendChild(p);
    document.getElementById("MessageList").appendChild(q);
});
```

Html

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#MessageList').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $('#MessageList')[0].scrollHeight
        }, 2000);
        var SessionId = document.getElementById("Id").value;
        console.log(SessionId);
        var form_data = {
            "SessionId": SessionId
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetHistory", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(form_data),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                var output = JSON.parse(result);
                for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
                    var p = document.createElement("span");
                    var q = document.createElement("li");
                    p.setAttribute("class", "Sender");
                    q.setAttribute("class", "Message");
                    p.textContent = output[i].Name + " - " + moment(output[i].CreatedOn).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
                    q.textContent = output[i].Message;
                    document.getElementById("MessageList").appendChild(p);
                    document.getElementById("MessageList").appendChild(q);
                }

            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h2>Session</h2>
    <hr />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="MessageListContainer">
                    <ul id="MessageList">
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentUser)
                <input class="form-control col-sm-12" id="Message" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <input id="Send" type="button" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/aspnet/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is the class output of your sender and receiver is: `p.setAttribute("class", "Sender");`
and  `q.setAttribute("class", "Message");`?

Comment: Yes. Sender is the name of the sender which is located on top of Message.

Comment: If the class output is what you expected I think you can add `.Sender{ /*your css styling*/}` into your css. And for receiver based on receiver class.

Comment: But the problem is that Sender class is applied universally and I don't differenciate between what I send and what the Receiver sends.

Comment: I see, are you able to differentiate between user (sender) and partner(receiver)? Based on query I suppose if you're using database, then add the class depending on the result.

Comment: I can try to compare and see If the username is same as the one in the httpcontext then set the css. Seems a little strange though.

Comment: If you are able to do so, then you might want to add `if` `else` to separate them. Example: If user then p.setAttribute("class", "Sender"); else p.setAttribute("class", "Receiver");

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX call that comes back as JSON appears to have a few fields like `Name` and `CreatedOn`. You can add an additional field server side for the `SessionId`, which you are injecting server-side anyway into your HTML. Then you can compare to see if the message's session matches yours. If so, then it is you and not the receiver. So you might have something like:

**JS**

```js
// You set this earlier on
var SessionId = document.getElementById("Id").value;

// ........ OTHER CODE IN BETWEEN

for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    var p = document.createElement("span");
    var q = document.createElement("li");

    // If session ID matches current session (i.e. you) then add different class
    if (output[i].SessionId === SessionId) {
        // It is you
        p.setAttribute("class", "Sender");
    } else {
        // It is other person
        p.setAttribute("class", "Receiver");
    }

    q.setAttribute("class", "Message");
    p.textContent = output[i].Name + " - " + moment(output[i].CreatedOn).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
    q.textContent = output[i].Message;
    document.getElementById("MessageList").appendChild(p);
    document.getElementById("MessageList").appendChild(q);
}
```

**CSS**

```css
.Sender {
    color: blue;
}
.Receiver {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: I'll try that. Currently the use of the ajax is when I refresh the page, it gets the chat history immediately. I'll need a  way to implement what you mentioned for when I type new messages

Comment: Instead of SessionID, you can use UserID. That would be a better solution long term in case the session drops and you end up with a new ID.